How the 'Secure Application ROM (SAROM)' works ? and how can be decrypted?
There is a protection product that i'm interested in analyzing and breaking it called SAROM that encrypts sensitive information that stored in the client-side such as API Keys/hardcoded stuff. I tried to understand it from an example that uses SAROM, which is an iOS app using SAROM as a data protection and IOSSecuritySuite as an anti-(jb/reversing/debugging/etc..) protection, but I couldn't. There are two mach-o binaries inside the example, the core which is a framework binary has the SAROM implementation, and the bundle that calling the SAROM call which is +[NSData dataFromSecureAppROMItem:] (located in core mach-o binary file). Now where are the encrypted data ? They are located in the 5341524f4d folder in the example. i uploaded it here, the +[NSData dataFromSecureAppROMItem:] method is the call that responsible of decrypting it.
P.S: i tried calling it using frida ObjC.classes.NSData.dataFromSecureAppROMItem_(ObjC.classes.NSString) but didn't work, probably because of how +[NSData dataFromSecureAppROMItem:] it works (the argument is the NSString's self: so probably the passed data has been accessed in an unusual way such as accessing it from an outside-the-method pointer) + IOSSecuritySuite making it more harder dynamically but the main thing is how SAROM works and it will be very helpful for understanding to write a script decrypting the data
